# Conflicting OpenCV and Matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have been trying to show images with opencv and plots with pyplot within the same script, but I will receive an error: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6` preceded by multiple lines of cryptic error log also shown on the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019556/matplotlib-crashing-tkinter-application).

The minimal code to reproduce the issue is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = np.ones((50, 50), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2], [1,3])
plt.show()
```

The problem does not occur if I only use opencv or pyplot exclusively. Only using both libraries in the same script generates the problem.

I am using python 2.7, opencv 2.4.13 and matplotlib 1.5.1 (also tried 2.0.0b) from a virtual environment on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

UPDATE: The code can be executed in a different order without errors:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2], [1,3])
plt.show()
img = np.ones((50, 50), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

UPDATE 2: Running the code in a debugger (PyCharm) executes without errors and shows both graphics. Apparently something in the interactive mode bypasses the issue.

Comment: Try adding this line `cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)` after the imports.

Comment: I don't think ocl is accessible in Python: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ocl'`

Comment: It is. I am putting this command in a script like his to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... Very old question.

This problem is caused by gtk version.

Generally, matplotlib use gtk2, but openCV 3.X use gtk3.

So, you need to downgrade your openCV version to openCV 2.x, upgrade your matplotlib version(use gtk3) or use only one between matplotlib or openCV 3.x