# Label and tick marks disappear when using log scale in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scale, logarithm

I need the y-axis of my graph to be on a log scale. When I do so, however, the y-axis' label, tick marks, and title disappear.

```
plt.figure(2)
plt.semilogy(data2[0, :, 0], sli)
plt.xlabel('n-value')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.title('Intensity vs. n-shell')
plt.show()
```

The `sli` values range from 1.0e-21 to 1.0e-8

[image: I'm not cool enough to post images]

When I zoom in far enough though, the label and title actually return but not the tick marks. Don't know if that matters, but thought I'd include it.

[image: !still not cool enough]

Thanks

**Edit: As it turns out, the code works fine, just not on my mac laptop. I tested the code on a friends computer running ubuntu and it worked perfectly. So, I guess my log scales don't like macs.
Still, anybody have any suggestions?**

"Update" for @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Nothing has changed.

[Graph produced from my code run with updated mplib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOvbM.png)

[Graph produced from @Engineero 's code run with updated mplib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUcvw.png)

Comment: "log scales don't like macs" - that's an interesting theory, but I suspect that you rather simply have a buggy version of matplotlib installed. You may update matplotlib and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Under your recommendation, I reinstalled matplotlib and checked the version i'm using (2.2.2). Still no luck :/

Comment: Can you update your question with a [mcve], i.e. a code one can run and the images you obtain from that updated version?

Comment: Added a section under the bold for you. Nothing has changed as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, seems like you aren't using the matplotlib version that you installed but still the old one.

Comment: Just tried updating again. This, among other things popped up:                                                 `Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`          Still same result

Comment: Sure, you have probably installed that correctly, but you are not *using*  it when running your code. Add `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)` inside the code that produces those images for you.

Comment: Ahh okay. My code says its running matplotlib version 1.3.1

Comment: Do you know how I can start using the correct version of matplotlib?

Comment: You need to use the correct python version, i.e the python version for which you installed matplotlib.

Comment: Ahhhhh!!! Yup, apparently I was running python 2.7 but I thought I was running 3. I changed my build system to run python 3 and it works now! Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`axis.set_yscale`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale) with [`axis.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params). Something like:

```
fig = plt.figure(2)
axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
axis.plot(data2[0, :, 0], sli)
axis.set_yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
axis.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', colors='black')
axis.set_xlabel('n-value')
axis.set_ylabel('Intensity')
axis.set_title('Intensity vs. n-shell')
plt.show()
```

Basically use the `axis` API. This is the only way I was ever able to get minor log-scale tick marks to work for me the way that I wanted...

Comment: I plugged your code in and got the exact same thing as my code. Still getting the "error." I'm guessing it has something to do with my mac since the code actually works fine on my friend's linux. Thanks for your contribution though!

Comment: @pierre700 Try adding `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` before you plot. If that doesn't work, try just 'Agg', maybe 'GTK'.

Comment: No luck. Tried all of them and they made what would be the graph just appear as a white window.

Comment: @pierre700 try the different backends listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43030607/3670871). If none of those work then I'm out of guesses.