# seabornplot + pyplot causes Mac OS X restart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I have the following code, that was actually intended to be a MWE for a different issue.
However, this causes something strange to video output and then signs out my user from Mac OS X,
when run. If I remove `plt.show()`, everything exits with exit code `0` except that the graph is not showing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = [1e4,1e4,1e4]
    p = [0.999,0.993,0.995]
    q = [1-x for x in p]
    K = len(n)
    num_simulations = 10000
    simulations = np.random.binomial(n,q,(num_simulations,len(n)))
    master_matrix = np.zeros((len(n),num_simulations))
    for j in range(K):
        master_matrix[j,:] = simulations[:,j]
    arr = np.zeros((num_simulations,K))
    for i in range(num_simulations):
        l = list(master_matrix[:,i])
        r1 = {j:l[j] for j in range(len(l))}
        arr[i,:] = np.array(list(r1.values()))
        assert len(arr[i,:]) == K
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=pd.Series([chr(i+ord('a')) for i in range(K)],name="group"),index=range(num_simulations))
    df1 = df1.melt(value_name="value")
    for i, value in enumerate(df1["group"].unique()):
        if value == 'c':
            df = df1.loc[df1["group"] == value]
            sns.distplot(df["value"])
            plt.show()
```

Comment: Possibly a bad backend interaction. Which backend are you trying to use (wild guess is tkagg)?  Can you make any matplotlib plots?

Comment: Using your keywords, and the SE thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026653/programmatically-choose-correct-backend-for-matplotlib-on-mac-os-x I found out it is `tkagg`. I am sure I could plot stuff in more complex settings using `matplotlib` inside `PyQt5`.

Comment: I found a temporary workaround by just saving, via `savefig`.

Comment: I would suggest installing `pyqt` and then setting the backend to `qt5agg` in your `.matplotlibrc` unless you have a burning reason to use `tkagg`