# Program ending early when using tkinter and pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to make a UI as an input, before closing this and then doing some plotting using pyplot. However, when I try to run a script using `tkinter` and importing `matplotlib.pyplot`, the program terminates at `root = Tk()` in the script, and will not run any commands after this line (including the mainloop).

Is there any way to use both `tkinter` and `matplotlib.pyplot` in the same script?

The UI I am running is:

```
from tkinter import *

class InputSelect(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, master, width=200, height=200)
        self.fillCanvas()

    def fillCanvas(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=200, height=200)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.aButton = Button(self, text="a", height=1, width=15, command=self.buttontest)
        self.aButtonWindow = self.canvas.create_window(100, 80, window=self.aButton)

        self.pack()

    def buttontest(self):
        print("buttontest")

def generateInputSelect():
    print("test")
    root = Tk()
    print("test2")
    app = InputSelect(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generateInputSelect()
```

This runs fine on its own, but if I use it in a separate script:

```
import ui
import matplotlib.pyplot


ui.generateInputSelect()
```

The console prints "test" and then closes, it doesn't reach "test2". This separate script runs as expected if I remove `import matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion and further research, running the program through terminal led me to the error `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

I was able to fix this error by setting the TkAgg backend manually using

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

as suggested by DonCristobal at [Matplotlib Crashing tkinter Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019556/matplotlib-crashing-tkinter-application)

This issue appears to be related to MacOS, which is why the error wasn't able to be reproduced by some users.