# import pandas causing debug mode to terminate

Tags: python, pandas

on my macbookpro macOS Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54), i am using PyCharm to debug my python code (Python3.6), i got error message in debug mode as below:

```
2019-02-11 17:59:46.750 python3.6[1727:27356] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9565936d0
2019-02-11 17:59:46.752 python3.6[1727:27356] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9565936d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2ff3aecd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5bff2720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2ffb8275 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2fedcb40 ___forwarding___ + 1486
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2fedc4e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011eb4231d TkpInit + 413
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011ea9a17e Initialize + 2622
    7   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x000000011e8c2a16 _tkinter_create + 1174
    8   python3.6                           0x000000010839c068 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 200
    9   python3.6                           0x000000010847161f call_function + 143
    10  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    11  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    12  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    13  python3.6                           0x00000001084722cc _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 364
    14  python3.6                           0x000000010831af80 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 320
    15  python3.6                           0x00000001083425f8 method_call + 136
    16  python3.6                           0x00000001083225ce PyObject_Call + 62
    17  python3.6                           0x00000001083c35b5 slot_tp_init + 117
    18  python3.6                           0x00000001083c7af1 type_call + 241
    19  python3.6                           0x000000010831aef1 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 177
    20  python3.6                           0x0000000108471718 call_function + 392
    21  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    22  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    23  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    24  python3.6                           0x0000000108471a8a fast_function + 362
    25  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    26  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    27  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    28  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    29  python3.6                           0x0000000108471a8a fast_function + 362
    30  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    31  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    32  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    33  python3.6                           0x00000001084719dc fast_function + 188
    34  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    35  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    36  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    37  python3.6                           0x00000001084719dc fast_function + 188
    38  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    39  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    40  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    41  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    42  python3.6                           0x0000000108471a8a fast_function + 362
    43  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    44  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    45  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    46  python3.6                           0x00000001084719dc fast_function + 188
    47  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    48  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    49  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984d01 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10625
    50  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    51  python3.6                           0x0000000108471a8a fast_function + 362
    52  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    53  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    54  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a98506d __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 11501
    55  python3.6                           0x00000001084719dc fast_function + 188
    56  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    57  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    58  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a984ad7 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 10071
    59  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    60  python3.6                           0x000000010845d129 builtin_exec + 345
    61  python3.6                           0x000000010839c068 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 200
    62  python3.6                           0x000000010847161f call_function + 143
    63  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    64  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64.cpython-36m-darwin.so 0x000000010a98506d __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 11501
    65  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    66  python3.6                           0x0000000108471a8a fast_function + 362
    67  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    68  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    69  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    70  python3.6                           0x0000000108471a8a fast_function + 362
    71  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    72  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    73  python3.6                           0x00000001084719dc fast_function + 188
    74  python3.6                           0x000000010847167c call_function + 236
    75  python3.6                           0x000000010846f175 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46837
    76  python3.6                           0x00000001084628c9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 425
    77  python3.6                           0x00000001084bb55c PyRun_FileExFlags + 252
    78  python3.6                           0x00000001084baa34 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 372
    79  python3.6                           0x00000001084e17c6 Py_Main + 3734
    80  python3.6                           0x0000000108312f59 main + 313
    81  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5d0c0ed9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

i tried to test which code line triggered this problem and felt wired to find that "import pandas as pd" caused it...
even with the code below, debug mode will end up with exception, when i toggle breakpoint at line "a = 1 + 2":

```
import pandas as pd

print("hello world")
a = 1 + 2
print(a)
```

Comment: I'm reading left and right that pandas points to matplotlib in some of its files, and that causes Mac OS issues. Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019556/matplotlib-crashing-tkinter-application/34109240#34109240), is it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by another library that `pandas` is using, the `matplotlib`.

And the solution is the same, [setting the `TkAgg` backend explictly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019556/matplotlib-crashing-tkinter-application/34109240#34109240). Add this to your code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

Or, if you don't want to edit the code, you can just use the following environment variable that `matplotlib` is reading:

```
MPLBACKEND=TkAgg
```